# Create Log file when a user make CRUD (create, update, delete) in Asp.Net Mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

How can I create a log file in my Asp.Net Mvc project for example when a registered user delete or Insert some item from/to database
My Car Class is as following

```
public class Car
    {
        public int CarId { get; set; }
        public string CarName { get; set; } 
        public int DeptId { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
    }


[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteCar(Car car)
        {
            using (context)
            {
                var carRecord = context.cars.Find(car.CarId);
                context.Cars.Remove(compRecord);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Or When Insert New Car

```
public async Task<ActionResult> InsertCar(Car car)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Insert into Car table 
                using (context)
                {
                    context.Cars.Add(car);
                    await context.SaveChangesAsync();


                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }


        }
```

I have no Idea how to begin to create Log file with following information
Date and time , deleted or Inserted (I mean what happened if he/she deleted, inserted...) , username
I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: Which version of .net are you on?

Comment: @nurdyguy Thank you for your respons. I can I check my version? in my ProjectName\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.3 ...?? Maybe this one? Thank you again!

Comment: Are you on .net core?  Visual Studio 2015 or 2017?

Comment: @nurdyguy Asp.Net Mvc, not Core and it is Visual Studio 2017, thank you